# How to resize divs into another Div

Tags: html, css

I'm struggeling to get the following working with css (width resizing):

[image]

I've 4 divs inside another div. Two of the two divs, 1st and 3d, have a text and are of fixed size (we don't know it in advance). The two other divs, A and B, should take each of them the 50% of the remaining space.

Ideally with a min. width, that make boxes 2 and 3 go to a new line.

Is this possible with pure css ?

Comment: Is it meant to also be responsive?

Comment: And yes it is possible with CSS. The parent div will always have a width of 100% for its children. So what you have to do is to use % for the child divs.   For example for text 20%, for a 30%, for text 10% and for B 40%

Comment: The text size is unknown, I don't know is size

Answer (score 0):

If you use `calc()` function maybe you can. If you can't with it, you can try with `flexbox` but is less compatibility with older browsers.

```
.content {
  font-size: 0;
}
.content > * {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.fixed {
  width: 50px;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d { 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.b, .d {
  width: calc(50px - 50px - 50%);
}
```

This means that `.b, .d` sizes are `.a - .c - 50%`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your looking for?

[image]

Here is a link to a live instance of it --> https://jsfiddle.net/ehnuzyo7/

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div>Variable Size</div>
    <div class="fixed">A</div>
    <div>Variable Size</div>
    <div class="fixed">B</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
#container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    width: 600px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#container>div{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    background: #5c5c5c;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
}

.fixed{
    max-width: 50px;
}
```